# addClass to array with setInterval in a loop

Tags: jquery, arrays, setinterval, addclass

**Background**: I'm using jQuery to add a class to each `<a>` element in a list one by one. I've got the `addClass()` part working - the `.highlighted` class is added to my first `<a>`, then removed and added to the second, etc.

**Problem**: I haven't been able to get the `addClass()` function to repeat once it reaches the last `<a>` element. I understand from searching on SO that `setInterval()` is a better way to approach this that `setTimeout()`, which I was using initially, but I haven't figured out how to specify that the function needs to repeat. Any help appreciated!

HTML:

```
  <a id="1">one</a>
  <a id="2">two</a>
  <a id="3">three</a>
  <a id="4">four</a>
  <a id="5">five</a>
```

JS:

```
var index = 0;
var $aArray = $('a');

function highlight(i){
    if(i>0){
        $aArray.eq(i-1).removeClass('highlight');
    }
    if(i == $aArray.length){
        return;
    }
    $aArray.eq(i).addClass('highlight');   

    setInterval(function() { highlight(i+1) },2500);
}

highlight(0);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple problems here:

1. You're starting a new `setInterval()` on every call to highlight and never stopping the previous one so you get multiple timers running at once.
2. When you hit your return statement - you never highlight anything.
3. Your wrapping back to the beginning logic isn't implemented properly.

It is generally simplest to implement array wrapping using the `%` operator.  You can do something simpler like this:

```
function highlight(items, index) {
    index = index % items.length;
    items.removeClass("highlight");
    items.eq(index).addClass('highlight');   
    setTimeout(function() {highlight(items, index + 1)}, 2500);
}

highlight($('a'), 0);
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/VLR4n/

Comment: Update implementation to remove all global variables.

Comment: thanks! What makes setTimeout the better option here?

Comment: @Marcatectura - you can make it work with either `setInterval()` or `setTimeout()`.  I find it easier to use `setTimeout()` because you don't have to keep track of the timerID in order to stop the interval timer when you want to be done.